# How can we make a flexipage accessible across packages/apps

Tags: flexipages, accessibilty

I have a flexipage in one package, with sobjecttype as O1, this flexipage is available in app A.
The flexipage is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<FlexiPage xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <flexiPageRegions>
        <componentInstances>
            <componentName>inventionDetailHeader</componentName>
        </componentInstances>
        <name>header</name>
        <type>Region</type>
    </flexiPageRegions>                               
    <masterLabel>Invention Record Page</masterLabel>
    <sobjectType>Awesome_Conf__Invention__c</sobjectType>
    <template>
        <name>flexipage:recordHomeSingleColTemplateDesktop</name>
    </template>
    <type>RecordPage</type>    
</FlexiPage>
```

The package xml is as follows :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CustomApplication xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">    
    <actionOverrides>
        <actionName>View</actionName>
        <comment>Action override created by Lightning App Builder during activation.</comment>
        <content>Invention_Record_Page</content>
        <formFactor>Large</formFactor>
        <skipRecordTypeSelect>false</skipRecordTypeSelect>
        <type>Flexipage</type>
        <pageOrSobjectType>Awesome_Conf__Invention__c</pageOrSobjectType>
    </actionOverrides>

    <brand>
        <headerColor>#06B76C</headerColor>
        <shouldOverrideOrgTheme>false</shouldOverrideOrgTheme>
    </brand>
    <description>Yada yada yada.</description>
    <formFactors>Large</formFactors>
    <isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>false</isNavAutoTempTabsDisabled>
    <isNavPersonalizationDisabled>false</isNavPersonalizationDisabled>
    <label>Awesome App</label>
    <navType>Standard</navType>
    <tabs>Awesome_Conf__Invention__c</tabs>
    <uiType>Lightning</uiType>
    <utilityBar>Awesome_App_UtilityBar</utilityBar>
</CustomApplication>
```

I've created a custom link in another object O2 in another app A2, this custom link opens the page where we can create object O1. 
I don't have code for the custom link, but only access to app A2 and it's object manager where I added the custom link with the following link :

```
/lightning/o/Awesome_Conf__Invention__c/new?c__RelatedParameter={!O2.Id}
```

But after creation of object O1, it tries to redirect to this flexipage but I get the error :

```
"List index out of bounds: 0
An unexpected error has occurred. Your solution provider has been notified"
```

If I open app A and see, object O1 is created and I can open the flexipage as well.

My question is what can I add/update in the flexipage to make it accessible through another app as well for a particular profile.

Comment: Welcome to SFSE. Please [edit] this post to include the actual metadata involved, including this custom link and any other code you're using.

Comment: I have edited the question with the required code sample